# VBA excel cell reference

Tags: vba, excel, reference

The issue I have is that I have a cell which I want to reference absolutely in a loop,
Here is my code

```
    Sheets("woo_import").Select
    range("A2").Select
Do While "=interspire!RC" <> ""
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=interspire!RC+add_on!R[1]C[1]"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).range("A1").Select
Loop
```

This cell in sheet add_on needs to be referenced absolutely add_on!R[1]C[1] while it loops through the range of cells in the interspire! sheet and enters the result in the sheet woo_import
Currently it uses relative references on all cells
I've tried various fixes, but with no success.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the error say? Also IMHO the `While` condition is very weird, it will ALWAYS be `False` and the loop should never run. You are simply comparing two strings `"=interspire!RC"` and `""` which is `False`

Comment: Did the answer below help? That is certainly the cause of the loop behaving this way. If it did, please mark it as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `While` condition is causing the problem.

It will ALWAYS be `False` and the loop should never run.

You are simply comparing two strings `"=interspire!RC"` and `""` which is `False`